# sharepoint groups in global audience

Tags: audiences

It's possible to use Sharepoint Groups when defining global audiences ? I have a collaboration site where I use Sharepoint Group(s) for giving permission.

I would like to show the link to the site only to those people. However, when I try to create the audience, I cannot find those Sharepoint Group. AD Groups are found, however.

Thanks
Michele

Comment: Also in the picker I can find an item with the name of the site. However, when I add to the audiences, i get "Non-existent Membership group (1B1DF4CF-46C6-4229-9CCA-8EAD5BF56CED)" at the audience summary screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint groups can be used with Web Parts to target content, they cannot be used to define global audiences.

For a deeper understanding, take a look at following article

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261958.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-a-web-part-to-a-specific-audience-HA010168840.aspx?CTT=3